# C++ vs Python | Read Memory

Tags: python, c++, pointers, memory, buffer

Have working code in `C++` and would like to get equivalent results with `Python`.
The idea is to retrieve data from memory using a specific process and a pointer. The result should look like this as it works in C++:
[image: C++ results]
Here is the C++ code:

```
hProcess = SOME_HANDLER
addr = SOME_POINTER
SIZE_T bytesRead = 0;
SIZE_T sizeBuff = 0x4000;
BYTE buff[sizeBuff];

ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, addr, buff, sizeBuff, &bytesRead);
```

In Python I have tried this:

```py
read_buffer = (ctypes.c_char * 0x4000)()
lp_buffer = ctypes.byref(read_buffer)
n_size = ctypes.sizeof(read_buffer)
lp_number_of_bytes_read = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
ctypes.windll.kernel32.ReadProcessMemory(self.handle, ctypes.c_void_p(lp_base_address), lp_buffer, n_size, lp_number_of_bytes_read)
result = read_buffer.value
```

Which gave me this result:

```
`b'hA\xdf\x01<B\xdf\x01\xb9\t\xba\t'`
```

I don't know what this means or if it contains anything useful.

Comment: Have you tried using [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result` is a value of type `bytes`, which represents a series of integer values between 0 and 255, inclusive.

When you display the each byte is show in one of two forms:

1. If the byte corresponds to a printable ASCII character, it is shown as that character.
2. Otherwise, it is shown as a hexadecimal integer prefixed with `\x`.

Iterating over a `bytes` value yields a sequence of `int` objects:

```
>>> list(result)
[104, 65, 223, 1, 60, 66, 223, 1, 185, 9, 186, 9]
```

(Note that `ord('h') == 104`, `ord('A') == 65`, `\xdf == 223`, etc.)

As mentioned in the comments, the `struct` package can be used to extract "usable" objects from a raw `bytes` value. For example, one could treat these 12 bytes as 3 unsigned 4-byte words in big-endian byte order:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack(">III", result)
(1749147393, 1011015425, 3104422409)
```

or 6 unsigned 2-byte words in little-endian byte order:

```
>>> struct.unpack("<HHHHHH", result)
(16744, 479, 16956, 479, 2489, 2490)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Nevertheless the output is no way close to matching my 16384 entry array from C++. I checked the pointers etc. are the same, so there must be another issue?

Comment: I see now that the memory is only read up to the first int object of value 0. Than it just stops reading and returns the incomplete bytes as posted above. I assume the ReadProcessMemory function assumes the data ends there due to the empty entry. Is there a fix for this? @chepner

Comment: Will open new question for this.